# How to animate an object more than once

Tags: jquery

I have the following click function using jQuery:

```
$('#buttonPic').on("click", function() {
    $("#box").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#boxMid").animate({
    height: "350px"
        }, 1500 );
    $("#boxBottom").animate({
        top: "0px"
        }, 1500 );
    $("#boxLayer").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#boxLayer").css("z-index", "890");
    $("#langBlock").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#language").css("color", "#d9d9d9");
});
```

When the button is clicked, `animate()` is called for two separate objects, but my issue is that once the object has been already animated, if I click the button again, the object does not reappear animated.

How can I make it so that every time I click the button, `animate()` will run.

Comment: Could you clarify the issue? On first click, height of #boxMid goes to 350px and top of #boxBottom goes to 0px. What do you want to happen on a second click?

Comment: @snookieordie on second click, I want the same thing to happen animated. But instead on second click, the #boxMid just appears normally with its new height and #boxTop with its new position.

Comment: After the animation runs for the first time, do you do anything to reset the height of #boxMid and top of #boxTop before running animation a second time?

Comment: @snookieordie no the only thing I do is make the wrapper around boxMId and boxTop become invisible `visibility: hidden`. That's after the box is closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reseting the height of #boxMid and the top of #boxTop in your function before the animations. This way, every time you click #buttonPic, these values will be reset and animated.

Without seeing more of your code, I can't give an exact example, but is this the kind of thing you want? https://jsfiddle.net/oez0488h/52/

```
$('#buttonPic').on("click", function() {
    $("#boxMid").css("height", "50px"); //reset to original height before animating
    $("#boxMid").animate({height: "350px"}, 1500);
});
```